# Jenkins groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: for class: Script1

Tags: jenkins, groovy

The purpose of this program is to replace all TFS user's password. It works if I directly use the userid and password inside the code, but fails with this error when I convert it to a paramaterized build.

```
Started by user Jirong Hu
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on public_jenprodslave_1 in workspace D:\public_jenprodslave_1\workspace\DevOps\Update-TFSPlugin-Password
param userid value : devops_test_user
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: userid_param_value for class: Script1


import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*
import hudson.util.Secret;
import hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm

def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver

def userid_param = "userid"
def userid_param_value = resolver.resolve(userid_param)
println "param ${userid_param} value : ${userid_param_value}"

def password_param = "password"
def password_param_value = resolver.resolve(password_param)
//println "param ${password_param} value : ${password_param_value}"


updateTFSPluginPassword(Hudson.instance.items)

def updateTFSPluginPassword(items) {    

    for(item in items) {
        if (item.class.canonicalName != 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder') {

          if (item.scm instanceof TeamFoundationServerScm) {                                    

            // Update the TFS user id here:
            //if (item.scm.getUserName() == 'devops_test_user') {
            if (item.scm.getUserName() == userid_param_value) {
                println("Working on project <$item.name>")
                println item.scm.getType()
                println item.scm.getServerUrl()
                println item.scm.getProjectPath()
                println item.scm.getWorkspaceName()
                println item.scm.isUseUpdate()
                println item.scm.getUserName()
                println item.scm.getPassword()

                // Update the TFS user password hash here:                  
                Secret secret = Secret.fromString(password_param_value)

                tfsSCM = new TeamFoundationServerScm(item.scm.getServerUrl(), 
                                                     item.scm.getProjectPath(), 
                                                     null, 
                                                     item.scm.isUseUpdate(), 
                                                     item.scm.getWorkspaceName(), 
                                                     item.scm.getUserName(), 
                                                     secret) 
                item.scm = tfsSCM

                println ("")

            }            
          }

        }  else  {              
            updateTFSPluginPassword(((com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) item).getItems())
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you may need to use [`Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) annotation, on the mentioned property. Please also have a look [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/groovy-goodness-change-scope-script.html).

Answer (score 9):

One of the reasons `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` is thrown is when you are trying to access a variable outside of its scope or you haven't defined that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the parameter is defined before accessing it:

```
if ( System.getenv('VARIABLE') ) {
  println "VARIABLE parameter exists, and its value is: " + VARIABLE
}
```

These methods might also work in the groovy script:

- binding.variables.containsKey('VARIABLE')
- currentBuild.buildVariableResolver.resolve('VARIABLE')
- build.environment.get('VARIABLE')